# How to store all keys from a specific value from SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, key-value

In my android app, I have a custom listview of installed apps with a checkbox next to it. I am using SharedPreferences to store the boolean true for checked and false for unchecked. The key value is the packagename of the app and the value is a boolean, true or false.

[image]

I am trying to store all the keys (packagenames) with the value-- true, all together and so then I can use the packagenames in another class for a specific task. However, I want the data structure that stores all the keys to stay the same and hold all the checked packagename keys even when the app is killed.

Currently, I am using code like this:

```
String findKey(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String value) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry: sharedPreferences.getAll()) {
        if (value.equals(entry.getValue())) {
            return entry.getKey();
        }
    }
    return null; // not found
}
```

I have tried researching but still unable to produce a solution.

[Get all SharedPreferences names and all their keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672949/get-all-sharedpreferences-names-and-all-their-keys)

[Gather all Strings from SharedPreference getAll() Method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718964/gather-all-strings-from-sharedpreference-getall-method)

How would I implement this correctly to get all my packagenames in a data structure that I can use in another class and have it stored with the same stuff even when the app is killed?

This is my code in my adapter class:

```
    for(int i= 0; i<packageList.size(); i++){
        PACKAGE_NAME = packageInfo.packageName;

        sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PACKAGE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


        holder.ck1.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean(PACKAGE_NAME,false));


    }

    holder.ck1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(packageInfo.packageName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

            if (holder.ck1.isChecked()) {
                itemChecked[position] = true;
                holder.ck1.setChecked(true);
                editor.putBoolean(packageInfo.packageName, true);

                editor.apply();

            } else {
                itemChecked[position] = false;
                holder.ck1.setChecked(false);
                editor.putBoolean(packageInfo.packageName, false);

                editor.apply();

            }

        }


    });
```

Comment: If all you need is a data structure then you could store a json string in Shared Preferences of the following format.
{ "<packagename1>":<boolean val1>,"<packagename2>":<boolean val2>}

and then retrieve the same and parse it using jsonobject and fetch the keys which denote your package names

Comment: I see. Is it possible to see an example of that? And will it be stored even when I exit the app and open it again

Answer (score 0):

Just extending from my comment.Here have a look.

```
    final String CHECKBOX_DATA="CHECKBOX_DATA";
    JSONObject js=new JSONObject();
    js.put("package.name1", true);
    js.put("package.name2", false);
    js.put("package.name3", true);
    js.put("package.name4", true);

SharePreferences prefs=context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(),Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.edit().putString(CHECKBOX_DATA, js.toString()).commit();
```

And then retrieve the same as

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(
            context.getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String json=prefs.getString(CHECKBOX_DATA, null);
JSONObject jsobj=new JSONObject(json);
Iterator<String> iter = jsobj.keys();

while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String key = iter.next();//This is your packagename
    try {
        boolean value = jsobj.getBoolean(key);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // Something went wrong!
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient for the OP to save the packagenames as an arraylist of strings in internal data storage?

Comment: If you seem to be speaking of SQlLite ,I suppose not. A simple key-pair valueset demands a simpler and easier storage for which this seemed the right solution. Had the structure been more complex then yes.

Comment: This does seem like a rather length way to achieve such a simple task. Look into http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getAll%28%29

Comment: What's with all the JSON? The OP has successfully store the checkbox states using sharedpreferences...all he is trying to do is retrieve the key values with true...

Comment: @ShyamalKeshav :While what you say retrieves all mapped values in SP how is one supposed to distuinguish between the packagenames and other values which OP might intend to store.
Also OP needed a structure for the storing the same hence the JSON seemed appropriate.

Comment: I am unable to implement the JSONObject way because the listview is populated based on the apps the user has installed. Yes, Shyamal Keshav is correct. I have successfully stored the checkbox states in the code above. I am sorry for any confusion. All I need to do is retrive the keys that have the value, true

Comment: This seems to be an inefficient way not to mention confusing as their is no way you could distinguish this dataset from any other <key-boolean> pair you may end up putting in your shared preferences. As @ShyamalKeshav suggested you may use getAll () method but this in no way would let you seggregate this checkbox dataset from other values(specifically boolean) you may put. 

However if these are the only values you are storing then go ahead with the getAll() method and then filter them by those which have their values true

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, now I understand your question.

In Android >=3.0 (API 11), you can store package name array by [putStringSet (String key, Set values)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putStringSet(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E))

In Android <3.0, you can combine all package name into one string, separate by "," because the package name cannot have ",".

For an example:

```
String allPackageName = "com.app1,com.app2,com.app3";
```

After that, save allPackageName in SharedPreference with a key:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("key_app_checked", allPackageName );
editor.commit();
```

Get all package name and split to an String array:

```
String packageNameChecked = sharedPref.getString("allPackageName");
if(packageNameChecked !=null){
      String [] arrPackageNameChecked = packageNameChecked.split(",");
      //Do somethings with arrPackageNameChecked ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

According your post, i don't know what exactly what do you want. Because SharedPreferences save many value in xml file, so you can access it in every where in your app and it not lost when the app is killed.

I saw some issue when you use SharedPref:

When save value:

- It must have editor.commit() after you change or store value.
- I think your code store each value in one SharedPreference file. It NOT necessary. You should save all value in one file with difference key.

You should read [this post](http://androidgreeve.blogspot.com/2014/01/How-to-use-Shared-Preferences-and-manage-User-Sessions.html), it will help you understand more about SharedPrefercence.

Comment: I successfully am using SharedPreferences to store the checkbox values. What I want is to store all the keys that hold the value true as persistent application data.

Comment: VAdaihiep, that is not true. editor.commit() is not needed. editor.apply() can also be used. Please refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html

Also, it seems that you don't understand what the OP did. He did store it in different keys. When he checked it off, the package name for the checked app was different. He is using a custom listview to display the user-installed apps.